# How to compare two datetime values between different rows with the same ID in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I would like to compare two datetime values from different rows that share a reference number. Both datetime values with the same reference are always from the same day, so the expected result is a column with the number of hours, minutes and seconds that passed between the datetime of each row and the first row with the same reference available in the table.

The problem is that there are usually more than two rows with the same reference and I always need to substract the earliest datetime available for this reference from each row's datetime.

How could I do this in SQL Server?

Best regards

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0):

You would simply use a window function.  Something like this:

```
select t.*,
       datediff(second, min(dt_col) over (partition by ref), dt_col) as time_in_seconds
from t;
```

Your question doesn't appear to be about formatting the result as a time, so this just returns the value as seconds.